# Faster rolling of random Gaussian vectors

Tags: python, c, optimization, numpy, random

For a Monte-Carlo like simulation, I need to pick at random thousands of random Gaussian vectors (that is, vectors having independently normally distributed entries). Each such vector is of fixed length (around 100).

NumPy has a method of achieving this:

```
import numpy.random
vectors = [numpy.random.normal(size=100) for _ in xrange(10000)]
```

NumPy's `random.normal` function is of linear complexity, with overhead for small size values. However, it looks like that overhead is not significant for `size=100` (perhaps around 30%, tested empirically; compare with the overhead for `size=1`, which is about 2300%). Perhaps I can save some of this overhead by rolling once, then splitting the array (haven't tried that yet).

However, it is still *much* too slow for my needs. Perhaps I'm too greedy here; I know that NumPy's randomization functions are written in `c` with optimization in mind; still,

```
timeit numpy.random.normal(size=100)
# 100000 loops, best of 3: 5.8 us per loop
```

(tested inside IPython, using its magic `%timeit`)

That makes ~0.06 seconds for 10k vectors. I was wondering whether there's a much faster method which will allow me to roll 10k vectors of size 100 (say) within less than 0.6ms, that is, 100 times faster. A solution may involve `c` extensions or whatever needed.

### Update

A very simple `c++` code, based on an [example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/normal_distribution) from `cppreference`, shows a much better performance:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()
{
    float x;

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::normal_distribution <> d(0,1);

    for(int i=0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
      x = d(gen);
    }
    std::cout << x << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

and time shows:

```
real    0m0.028s
user    0m0.020s
sys     0m0.004s
```

which is about X20 times faster than what NumPy gives. However, I am not sure about the overhead of c-extensions for python, and I have no intuition about whether this can become a python function which is faster than `numpy.random.normal`.

Comment: `np.random.randn(100, 10000)`

Comment: @behzad.nouri: thanks for your reply! However, this only improved my 0.06 seconds to about 0.04 seconds, still far from what I was hoping to find.

Comment: with numpy >= 1.9 you can use threads to speed it up, but it can't get any faster than that using numpy. numpy uses the box muller method, you might get better performance with a cextension using the ziggurat method.

Comment: @jtaylor - thanks; I believe that this will be way beyond my `c` skills. However, it is probably a good direction to look at.

Comment: How normal should your random numbers be, i.e. how much error in the distribution you can have. Is it just "approximately normal"? Then there might be ways to speed things up.

Comment: I guess "approximately normal" should be all right, but I am not sure how to estimate "how much error" I can have.